# World Series betting problem

Tags: probability, gambling

We are trying to bet 100 dollars on team A winning a best of five series, but we cant bet on the entire series, just single games. How can we place a bet on single games such that at the end of the series if A wins, we have 200 dollars, and if B wins we have 0 dollars.

The solutions to this problem I have seen all make use a tree diagrams and seem to pull out numbers from thin air, so I was looking for a more systematic approach to solve the problem so that it could be applied to best of 7/9 series as well

Comment: You need to read the solutions more carefully.  They do not pull numbers out of thin air.  They choose the amount to bet to achieve the result you are looking for.  For example, if the series is tied $2-2$ you want to bet $100$ dollars and you better be even at that point  Can you understand both of these claims?

Comment: Yeah that would make sense

Comment: Then if the series is $2-1$ you need to be ahead at that point by 100 so you can bet 100.  If your team wins they win the series and you are $+200$.  If they lose they are $2-2$ and you are even as required.  Yes, it is tracing back the tree, but each step is well defined.

Comment: If you search win series bet you find several approaches to this question.